# Color of font family that has outline only

Tags: css, font-face

I have a font that has outline only. It does not have any fill color. Here you can see this fone.

http://www.dafont.com/comica-bd.font

I am using this font in my webpage (fontface). When I change color of font, its outline is changed. **Is there a way to change fill color as well using CSS?** Or is my last option to use images?

This is what i want: 
[image: This is what I want to do]

This is what I could do with CSS and fontface. 
[image]

Any CSS property to fill background or something.?

Comment: I have not come across such thing yet. And I don't think you could fill color into the font as given in your question.

Comment: if the font has only outline, then the color provided by CSS will color the outline.

Comment: @esimov I have added images for you.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. I think you need to fallback to images instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to fill the font in css. The blank space can not be considered part of the font for css purposes.

Answer (score 0):

** EDIT - I hadn't checked this in other browsers. It's a pretty gross implementation. I wouldn't recommend doing anything like this. **

This solution uses HTML5, CSS3 and, as such, has some browser support conditions.

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/keithwyland/pen/tbfcE) http://codepen.io/keithwyland/pen/tbfcE (code below if codepen doesn't work)

I've used the Google Web Font Jacques Francois Shadow (http://www.google.com/webfonts) and it's sister font Jacques Francois. Basically, the shadow font has an outline font like the one you're using. The other font is the same but not outline, it's filled in.

What I did was set a data- attribute to repeat the text of the element, then use that in the CSS. I'm also using a pseudo element to spit out the value of that data attribute. It's not perfect (mostly the spacing), but what would help is if your 2nd font could have the exact letter width as your original font and just be filled in instead of outline.

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jacques+Francois+Shadow);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jacques+Francois);

body {
    background-color: red;
    font-family: 'Jacques Francois Shadow', cursive;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 300%;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1:after {
    font-family: 'Jacques Francois', cursive;
    content: attr(data-ttl);
    position: absolute;
    color: blue;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    word-spacing: -0.055em;
  text-shadow:  1px 0 blue;
  z-index: -1;
}

p {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

HTML

```
<h1 data-ttl="Stuff with fill">Stuff with fill</h1>
<p>No fill</p>
```

Comment: I like the term "brilliant hack"